# How to reload tableview from another controlview swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, favorites

In my iOS app, I have DetailController and FavoriteViewController for favorite word how to auto reload table view after added word to favorite?

it is fun to send data to my db in DetailController

```
@IBAction func favs(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if listMean[sender.tag].Favorite == 1 {
            listMean[sender.tag].Favorite  = 0
        }
        else {
            listMean[sender.tag].Favorite = 1
        }

        Singleton.ShareInstance.dbHelper.updateFavorite(newMean: listMean[sender.tag])
    }
```

it is my FavoriteViewController

```
import UIKit

class FavoriteViewController: UITableViewController {


        var listFavorite = [FavoriteModel]()
        var dbHelper = DatabaseHelper()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            loadAllWords()
                   }



    func relodaTableview() {
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
        func loadAllWords(){
            listFavorite = dbHelper.getAllFavorite()
            tableView.dataSource = self
            tableView.delegate = self
                   }


        override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            navigationItem.title = nil
            if segue.identifier == (Singleton.ShareInstance.enwordSelected?.Word){
                navigationItem.title = (Singleton.ShareInstance.enwordSelected?.Word)
            }

        }


        override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

            return 1

        }

        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return listFavorite.count

        }

        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! FavoriteViewCell

                cell.favoriteword = listFavorite[indexPath.row]

                return cell

        }


        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            return 45
        }


        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

            Singleton.ShareInstance.favoriteSelected = listFavorite[indexPath.row]


            let des = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailController")
            navigationController?.pushViewController(des!, animated: true)

        }


}
```

Comment: use Delegate methods

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegate pattern or callback method.
Delegate pattern :
you should create a protocol

```
protocol FavoriteDetailDelegate {
func updateTableView() }
```

your view controller conform your protocol for delegate

```
extension FavoriteViewController: FavoriteDetailDelegate {
func updateTableView() {
    print("Something update etc ...")
} }
```

and your detail page is delegate your table view :

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "detailSegue" {
        let detailVC = segue.destination as! FavoriteDetailViewController
        detailVC.delegate = self
    }
}
```

and you can update in Detail view controller

```
@IBAction func update(_ sender: UIButton) {
    delegate.updateTableView()
}
```

or you can use callback method:
Create a callback in Detail view controller

```
var callback: ((String) -> Void)!
@IBAction func update(_ sender: UIButton) {
    callback("test")
}
```

in view controller

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "detailSegue" {
        let detailVC = segue.destination as! FavoriteDetailViewController
        detailVC.callback = {
            str in
            print("String \(str)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add observer for reload table

```
NotificationCenter.default().addObserver(self, selector: Selector(("relodaTableview")), name: "loadedPost", object: nil)
```

And from another view controller there you want to reload table of FavoriteViewController post notification for reload

```
NotificationCenter.default().post(NSNotification(name: "loadedPost" as NSNotification.Name, object: nil) as Notification)
```

Comment: In Swift 3 this will not work @Mr. Jignesh Mayani :)

Comment: sure @ Mr Bhavik shah